# reactjs checkboxlist component - Updating state changes in parent

Tags: javascript, checkbox, reactjs, web-component

I have a bunch of  checkbox-list requirements. I will explain in detail. I have a bunch of languages say:

```
var languages = ["English", "German", "French", "Spanish", "Mandarin", "Tamil"]
```

I have a parent component which has a form where I have four sections, Say:

```
class Page extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <h1>CanSpeak</h1> <chkboxlist someProp="speak" />
        <h1>CanSpeak</h1> <chkboxlist someProp="read" />
        <h1>CanSpeak</h1> <chkboxlist someProp="write" />
        <h1>CanSpeak</h1> <chkboxlist someProp="understand" />
        <button
          onClick={e => {
            console.log("Need the various chkboxlist values here");
            e.preventDefault();
          }}
        >
          Save
        </button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

I want the chkboxlist component to keep track of the list of selected languages in each section and make them available in the "Save" button click handler. I wish to keep track of the state changes (list of selected languages under each section) in the "Page" component.

I do not want to use redux or some such external state management.

Now what is the way to create this chkboxlist component such that the state changes can be tracked in the parent Page component ? Are there any existing components which will fit this requirement and is used widely in the react ecosystem without having to reinvent the wheel ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if pulling in a seperate component would be really useful - as it's only a really tiny piece of functionality.

Working fiddle here: 
https://jsbin.com/tusakexire/edit?html,js,output

You could do something like:

```
class Chkboxlist extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props) 
      this.state = {}
      props.values.map((v, i) => {
          this.state[v] = false
      })
  }

  onChange(key, value) {
      this.setState({ [key]: value }, (state) => {
          this.props.onChange(this.state)
      })
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <div className="list-group-item form-group">
                {this.props.values.map((value, i) => (
                    <div className="checkbox" key={i}>
                        <label>
                            <input 
                                onChange={(e) => this.onChange(value, e.target.checked)} 
                                type='checkbox' 
                                value={this.state[value]}
                            />
                            {value}
                        </label>
                    </div>
                ))}
          </div>
      )
  }
}

class Page extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {}
  }

  onChange(name, values) {
      this.setState({ [name]: values })
  }

  render() {
    const languages = ["English", "German", "French", "Spanish", "Mandarin", "Tamil"]


    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <form className="form">

                <div className="list-group col-xs-6">
                    <h4>Can Speak</h4> 
                    <Chkboxlist 
                        onChange={(values) => this.onChange('speak', values)}
                        values={languages}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="list-group col-xs-6">
                    <h4>Can Read</h4> 
                    <Chkboxlist 
                        onChange={(values) => this.onChange('read', values)}
                        values={languages}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="list-group col-xs-6">
                    <h4>Can Write</h4> 
                    <Chkboxlist 
                        onChange={(values) => this.onChange('write', values)}
                        values={languages}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="list-group col-xs-6">
                    <h4>Can Understand</h4> 
                    <Chkboxlist 
                        onChange={(values) => this.onChange('understand', values)}
                        values={languages}
                    />
                </div>

                <button
                  className="btn btn-primary"
                  onClick={(e) => {
                    console.log(this.state);
                    e.preventDefault();
                  }}
                >
                  Save
                </button>
              </form>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Page />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: Your ChkboxList constructor gives two eslint warnings (arrow function not returning a value, setState not being called and state value mutated directly). So, I replaced the constructor with: `constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var values = {};
    props.values.forEach(function(element) {
      values[element] = false;
    }, this);
    this.state = values;
  }` I request that you update the source if possible. Thanks.

Comment: @mathias.horn updated the fiddle (looked like the old one had changed?)